# With using FM220U Bio-metric finger print want read the data from Adhar Card

Tags: java, android

I have connected FM220U with my PC now i want to read the data in android studio by using adhar API's please tell me how is it possible.

Comment: please post what you've tried so far

Comment: I need just info how should i do this.

Comment: If you need info on how to proceed, view the sample code here https://acpl.in.net/RdService.html